# If unions of two families sets are disjoint then families of sets are disjoint too.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I have read that theorem "Suppose $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ are families of sets. If $\cup\mathcal{F}$ and $\cup\mathcal{G}$ are disjoint, the so are $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$" is incorrect. But I can not understand way. May somebody explain to me why this theorem is wrong or provide a counterexample?

Comment: If they are the same than unions can not be disjoint.

Comment: There are exactly two ways that the two families can be the same and still have disjoint unions ...

Comment: @HenningMakholm do you mean, empty families and families which contain empty set?

Comment: x @Andrey: Yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\mathcal F$ and $\mathcal G$ both have $\varnothing$ as an element, their unions can still be disjoint.

As a concrete example, we could take $\mathcal F=\{\varnothing,\{42\},\{1,2,3\}\}$ and $\mathcal G=\{\varnothing,\{7\}\}$.